# Logrotate not working with "Maxsize" with cron job configured

Tags: centos, logging, cron, log-files, logrotate

Thanks in advance.
I have a server acting as a syslog-ng server  and receiving logs from multiple network devices.
These files increase in size quickly so I created logrotate file with the below configurations.

```
    /syslog-ng/logs/devices/*.log
 {
   maxsize 10M
   notifempty                 # Do not rotate the log if it is empty
   compress                   # Old versions of log files are compressed with gzip
   hourly                     # Interval
   dateext                    # Archive old versions of log files adding a daily extension
   missingok                  # If the log file is missing, go on to the next one without issuing an error message
   rotate 5
   postrotate
   /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2>/dev/null` 2 >/dev/null || true endscript
   endscript
}
```

I wanted it to rotate if an hour passes or if size of any of these log files reaches 10 MBytes. However this is not happening. I learned that logrotate need to be run by a cron job in order for it to take any effect so I added the below entry to

```
    /etc/cron.d/
[root@proem cron.d]# cat syslog-logrotate-15mins
*/10 * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/splunk-logrotate >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Files still reach 200 and 300 Mbytes without logrotate taking effect, however the hourly logrotate is working and the max-size not taking any effect.

If you look at the files inside the directory to be rotated

```
total 2441816
drwxr-x--- 2 bin bin      8192 May 28 11:50 .
drwxr-x--- 3 bin bin        21 May  7 11:31 ..
-rw------- 1 bin bin 288410030 May 28 12:00 ASA-10.40.36.19.log
-rw------- 1 bin bin   9160117 May 28 07:00 ASA-10.40.36.19.log-2019052807.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  10237580 May 28 08:00 ASA-10.40.36.19.log-2019052808.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  19497590 May 28 09:00 ASA-10.40.36.19.log-2019052809.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  25640952 May 28 10:00 ASA-10.40.36.19.log-2019052810.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  24734338 May 28 11:00 ASA-10.40.36.19.log-2019052811.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin    292677 May 28 11:59 ASA-10.40.36.20.log
-rw------- 1 bin bin      4763 May 28 06:51 ASA-10.40.36.20.log-2019052807.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin       627 May 28 07:55 ASA-10.40.36.20.log-2019052808.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin      4842 May 28 08:59 ASA-10.40.36.20.log-2019052809.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin      9432 May 28 09:59 ASA-10.40.36.20.log-2019052810.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin      8106 May 28 10:59 ASA-10.40.36.20.log-2019052811.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin   4085275 May 28 06:59 Bluecoat-proxy.log-2019052807.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin   4695767 May 28 08:00 Bluecoat-proxy.log-2019052808.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  13686609 May 28 09:00 Bluecoat-proxy.log-2019052809.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  18211983 May 28 10:00 Bluecoat-proxy.log-2019052810.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin   9524946 May 28 10:35 Bluecoat-proxy.log-2019052811.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin 403974411 May 28 12:00 Firepower-10.40.82.15.log
-rw------- 1 bin bin   6592767 May 28 06:59 Firepower-10.40.82.15.log-2019052807.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin   7364536 May 28 07:59 Firepower-10.40.82.15.log-2019052808.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  14523366 May 28 09:00 Firepower-10.40.82.15.log-2019052809.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  19629133 May 28 09:59 Firepower-10.40.82.15.log-2019052810.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  19185954 May 28 10:59 Firepower-10.40.82.15.log-2019052811.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin    184590 May 28 11:59 Firepower-10.40.82.25.log
-rw------- 1 bin bin      6146 May 28 06:59 Firepower-10.40.82.25.log-2019052807.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin      6319 May 28 07:59 Firepower-10.40.82.25.log-2019052808.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin      5441 May 28 08:59 Firepower-10.40.82.25.log-2019052809.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin      5220 May 28 09:59 Firepower-10.40.82.25.log-2019052810.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin      5225 May 28 10:59 Firepower-10.40.82.25.log-2019052811.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin 633384651 May 28 12:00 Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log
-rw------- 1 bin bin   5603673 May 28 07:00 Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log-2019052807.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin   5722379 May 28 08:00 Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log-2019052808.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin   6466792 May 28 09:00 Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log-2019052809.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin   7398515 May 28 10:00 Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log-2019052810.gz
-rw------- 1 bin bin  39241773 May 28 11:00 Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log-2019052811.gz
```

If you notice it rotates every hour and the max-size entry isn't taking any effect.

I tried to do a logrotate -d just to see and show you the details

```
[root@proem logrotate.d]# logrotate -d splunk-logrotate
reading config file splunk-logrotate
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 1 logs

    rotating pattern: /syslog-ng/logs/devices/*.log
      hourly (5 rotations)
    empty log files are not rotated, log files >= 10485760 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
    considering log /syslog-ng/logs/devices/ASA-10.40.36.19.log
      log needs rotating
    considering log /syslog-ng/logs/devices/ASA-10.40.36.20.log
      log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)considering log /syslog-ng/logs/devices/Firepower-10.40.82.15.log
      log needs rotating
    considering log /syslog-ng/logs/devices/Firepower-10.40.82.25.log
      log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)considering log /syslog-ng/logs/devices/Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log
      log needs rotating
    rotating log /syslog-ng/logs/devices/ASA-10.40.36.19.log, log->rotateCount is 5
    dateext suffix '-2019052811'
    glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    destination /syslog-ng/logs/devices/ASA-10.40.36.19.log-2019052811.gz already exists, skipping rotation
    rotating log /syslog-ng/logs/devices/Firepower-10.40.82.15.log, log->rotateCount is 5
    dateext suffix '-2019052811'
    glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    destination /syslog-ng/logs/devices/Firepower-10.40.82.15.log-2019052811.gz already exists, skipping rotation
    rotating log /syslog-ng/logs/devices/Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log, log->rotateCount is 5
    dateext suffix '-2019052811'
    glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    destination /syslog-ng/logs/devices/Paloalto-10.40.82.18.log-2019052811.gz already exists, skipping rotation
```

Only the hourly logrotate works.  I tried  both "Size" and "maxsize"  to the same effect. I have also added the logrotate script in the hourly cron jobs.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that `/10` runs your "15mins" script every 10 minutes (if code and comments don't agree, both are probably wrong). And don't also add logrotate to the hourly cron job as very strange things may happen with 2 logrotate processes running together.

Comment: It is a mistake from my side, /10 and /15 really makes no different to me it doesn't work still. Only works after 1 hour regardless of size.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that it is trying to rotate when the file is exceeding the maxsize when logrotate is run, however as the `dateext` only has an hourly part this would cause the previous rotated file to be overwritten.

I suggest adding a config line:

```
dateformat -%Y%m%d%H%M
```

so that minutes also form part of the rotated filename.

Comment: I will add the line in the logrotate configuration and let you know how it turns out.